How to resolve "Crystal Report load" error
Private Sub frmReportView_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        crv.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow
        crv.ReportSource = cr
        'cr.VerifyDatabase()
        cr.RecordSelectionFormula = SelFormula

        crv.Refresh()
        crv.RefreshReport()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString())
    End Try    
End Sub

I am trying to use the above code, but it's giving me a "crystal report load" error. I am using Crystal Reports 2005 and Visual Studio 2008.
